# Use quaternion in place of rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector n1, I find `u = n1 x {0,1,0}`.
Then I find `theta = acos(n1 . {0,1,0})`.

Then I form an axis-angle rotation matrix from u and theta. Then I form a rotation quaternion from that rotation matrix.

My question is: Can I easily find n1 given the rotation quaternion?

---

---

---

*Another version of this question, with more background information:*

Assume the reference "up" is Y, and positive Z goes into your screen.

I have a 3D plane defined by it's normal, n1. n1_y is always positive.

I have a 3-vector, n2, which is relative to the XZ plane. I want to find the vector that results from rotating n2 so that it is relative to the plane defined by n1.

Currently, I accomplish this by finding the axis of rotation, by taking n1 cross the XZ unit vector:

```
float3 u = cross(n1, float3(0,1,0));
```

Then I find the angle to rotate by:

```
float theta = acos(dot(float3(0,1,0), n1));
```

Then I form a rotation matrix from the axis and angle:

```
float3x3 rotMatrix = float3x3(
        cos(theta) + u.x*u.x*(1-cos(theta)), u.x*u.y*(1-cos(theta))-u.z*sin(theta), u.x*u.z*(1-cos(theta)) + u.y*sin(theta),
        u.y*u.x*(1-cos(theta)) + u.z*sin(theta), cos(theta) + u.y*u.y*(1-cos(theta)), u.y*u.z*(1-cos(theta))-u.x*sin(theta),
        u.z*u.x*(1-cos(theta)) - u.y*sin(theta), u.z*u.y*(1-cos(theta))+u.x*sin(theta), cos(theta)+u.z*u.z*(1-cos(theta))
    );
```

Then I multiply n2 by the rotation matrix to yield the new vector I wanted.

Currently n1 is precomputed and stored, so I have to find the axis and angle and rotation matrix from n1.

I was hoping there is a way to store a quaternion instead (representing the axis and angle), and easily recover the normal n1 from that quaternion. Is there a way to do that? How?

Or, is there another more efficient way to do this computation?

Comment: I'm new at asking math questions (this is my first one here), so please tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: Given a quaternion, why not convert it to a rotation matrix $R$, and then recover $n_1$ as $n_1=R^Tv$, where  $v=[0,1,0]^T$.

Comment: BTW, using latex can make the question more clear and easier to read:)

Comment: Shiyu, do I just write the latex in a Ctrl+K code block? When writing code in comments you put it in ` marks, what do you use for latex in comments?

Comment: Shiyu, you should post your answer as an answer. I think that will work, I'll try it now.

Comment: @TheBigO: no code block. \$ \theta \$ will give $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=[0,1,0]^T$. Suppose $R$ is the rotation matrix you obtained. Then $R$ can rotate vector $n_1$ to $v$. That is $Rn_1=v$. Hence $n_1=R^Tv$.

So once you have a quaternion, you can convert it to a rotation matrix $R$ first. Then recover the $n_1$ as $n_1=R^Tv$.

Comment: I believe this is the right idea, but you don't need to convert the quaternion to a rotation matrix first; you can simply invert the quaternion and apply it to $v$.

Comment: @Rahul: I think your answer is better.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Rahul, feel free to add that as an answer, for some rep.